# be subscribed to pubsub but publish anonymously like in MUC

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire

I don't see the possibility in a pubsub to be subscribed with my JID but sometimes publish anonymously like in the MUC. I slowly but surely realize that pubsub is not that flexible as it actually should be.. too bad..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "publish anonymously".

The publisher of a pubsub item is not known unless the server includes it in the notification, which per XEP-0060 [is optional](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#publisher-publish-success-publisher).